# 1/60 Hz Counter/Divider

Tags: clock, counter, timing, divider

I have a fairly precise 1 Hz square wave that I would like to divide down to 1/60 Hz (1 pulse per minute). I want a one-chip solution and I am not having a lot of luck with this. I do not want a microprocessor or similar solution. I found a "programmable divide by n counter" [CD74HC4059](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4059.pdf?ts=1655220198402) but I am having a heck of a time decoding the setting table they provide. I found datasheets from Phillips and TI, but both are unclear to me. I simply want to divide my 1Hz down to 1/60 Hz so that my output pin goes high once per minute. Can someone help me with the wiring settings for this?

Comment: Please provide a link to the document that you are having trouble understanding.

Comment: Any MCU would do it.

Comment: I have added a link to the Datasheet, and I do not want an MCU, CPLD, or ASIC solution

Comment: @AustinFox Your "one-chip solution" is either an MCU or an ASIC by definition, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: MCU would definitely work, but I am trying to keep this in the hardware world, is there a reason the 4059 wont work for my use if I can figure out which pins to set for n=60 division?

Comment: @Hearth Well, a 6-bit counter is just enough

Comment: but the 74xx4059 is an ASIC, so you ruled that out!

Comment: Then you need to build logic gates out of discreets. Perhaps some 1950s or 60s text book may have something which can give you tips. I would suspect you end up in the 100 transistor range. Perhaps just a synchronous motor with a 1/60 gearbox and a cam triggering a switch would do the job too. Perhaps there is even a mechanical clock which has minute output signal.

Comment: (by the way, the comments saying "use a microcontroller!" are a bit short, because you don't get an explanation for why that might be appropriate: You say you're having a hard time configuring the state machine "74xx4059 counter"; well, what if there was a state machine that could have 60 states, and you switch from one to the other, always in order, and at the 60th jump back to the 1st? That would be the counter you want to build. And, lo, what a processor is: a state machine with one or multiple arithmetic state holders (registers) that allow you to set state transition rules arbitrarily,

Comment: so-called "programs". Whether setting up a 74xx4059 could be counted as "programming" is arguable, but it's definitely setting up a hard-to-configure state machine. If you can replace that with a state machine that you find easy to configure, that's not a bad choice! And I'd concur, using a cheap microcontroller here can solve this pretty elegantly, at low (developer-visible) complexity.)

Comment: All very true @MarcusMüller , and I appreciate your thoughtful responses. A microcontroller is indeed a more streamlined solution for what is admittedly a problem that has already been solved a million times. However it was important to me to try and make this project as back-to-basics as possible, I wanted to have fun with some more elementary logic states and see what can be done without resorting to microcontrollers.

Comment: all understandable, but I'm not convinced a 74xx4059 qualifies for me as "back-to-basics as possible", which I admit is my personal opinion. Doing this in a CPLD would be much more basic, IMHO! I think the engineers who invented these kinds of counters would also see it similarly: this is mid-1970s tech, if I had to guess (the datasheets only reach back to 1993, but that's when Philips bought… anyways), and back in the day microcontrollers were prohibitively expensive; however, this IC is basically the "highest complexity you'd do instead of building a simple processor", I'd guess, under

Comment: completely different financial and power constraints considering the *available* microcontrollers of the day.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Are we approaching XY problem territory?

Comment: Possibly, I will test the solution provided by hobbs. Maybe the next iteration of this project will have to involve an MCU.

Comment: @winny don't think so; The problem that Austin wants to solve is "how to program the 4059", I'd say

Answer (score 3):

You want to divide by 60. There are several options that would work for the 74HC4059 but the simplest is mode = 2 (Ka, Kb, Kc all high), and a preset of 0030+0 (J5, J6 high, all others low). Admittedly, the documentation is kind of scattered, but the datasheet does tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Thank you, I will test this and see if I get the outcome I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I have not prototyped this with a 555, but I've done something similar.

A monostable with a 1 Hz clock signal at its trigger input and a period of 59.1 seconds will be high for 59 seconds, go low the less than 1 second, and then go high again at the start of the 60th second.  A 555 is not a true retriggerable monostable, and in this case that is good.  As a monostable, the 555 has other issues, so this circuit needs a differentiator at the Trigger input.

The 555 monostable period is:  t = 1.055 x R x C

Better to split R into one fixed resistor and one trimpot.  They should have similar temperature coefficients.  The split between fixed and variable values depends on the tolerance of the timing capacitor; the worse the tolerance, the more adjustment range you will need.

1.054651 is a correction factor because for an exponential voltage ramp across a capacitor, 1 time constant is 63.212% of Vcc, while the 555 transition level is 66.667%.

You don't say anything about the operating environment of the circuit, so the timing capacitor can be anywhere between 6 cents and 6 dollars.